# Updating data from other form

Tags: c#

I have tow form,`ListFrom`, and `DetailForm`
In the `ListForm` I have a devexpress grid and some button(add, delete, edit)
In the `DetailForm` I have some textboxes and some button(save,delete,next,previous)
well I have to senario
1 - I open the ListForm and I click on a product to modify it a got the `DetailForm` opened, I make some modification and I save,then i should have my grid in the `ListForm` refreshed with the new value.for this I have this code

In the ListFrom

```
FrmProduit frm = new FrmProduit(monProduit.Id) { MdiParent = this.MdiParent};
frm.updateDataInGridView += new System.Action(refereshGridView);
frm.Show();
```

in the detailform

```
 if (updateDataInGridView != null)
      updateDataInGridView();
```

well in this scenario everything is OK

second scenario
If I open the `detailFrom`,and after that I open the `listForm`, I make some change in the `detailFrom` and I click save `updateDataInGridView` in this case is null and then the grid is not refreshed
anyone have suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a shared `BindingSource` that both forms would use to show data. If any item is changed in `BindingSource` it takes care to notify all controls bind to it and so it would refresh grid automatically.

Second approach is to make `refereshGridView` method public and in `DetailForm` on `save click` do this:

```
var lists = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ListFrom));

foreach (var listform in lists)
{
    listform.refereshGridView();
}
```

I did not use `FirstOrDefault` as maybe there is more than one `listform` opened.

**EDIT about Binding Source**

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial) is quite good tutorial so please take a look.

Below is a fast-written far from best example of stretch I did:

```
internal static class DataSources
{
     private static BindingSource bs;

     public static BindingSource CerateDataSource(List<object> yourObjects)
     {
          bs = new BindingSource();
          bs.DataSource = yourObjects;
     }

     public static BindingSource GetDataSource()
     {
          return bs;
     }

     public static void Reset()
     {
          bs.ResetBindings(false);
     }
}
```

and then in your `listview`

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = DataSources.GetData();
```

and in `detailsview` where you are editing one of the objects from `BindingSource` on save you would have to call: `DataSources.Reset();`. This is just a markup, but hopefully you get the idea :).

Comment: Can be simply written as `Application.OpenForms.OfType<ListFrom>()`

Comment: Thank't that's good and it works fine, i will be grateful if you explain to me the first opproach : )

Answer (score 0):

You must always be sure you are referring to the current instance of `detailform`, thus declare on your `listForm`

```
detailform obj = (detailform)Application.OpenForms["detailform"];
```

And every time you call `detailform` from `listForm` do it by `obj` e.g:

```
obj.Show()
```